# How do I remap the caps lock key to the backspace key?

Tags: keyboard, xmodmap, remapping, colemak

I have grown very comfortable to my Colemak keyboard layout (my typing speed has doubled since I started using it). My only problem with it is that there is no caps lock key because under this layout because the caps lock key is a second backspace key. I really miss caps lock so I would like to change the backspace key on the top right corner of my keyboard  (not the one right next to the "a") into a caps lock key. Is there a way to do this using xmodmap or some other tool? I am using Xfce.

Comment: +1 for the general interest of the question, but I really can't imagine why someone can miss caps lock... ;-) It's the first thing I ditch on any keyboard (disable it and remap to Compose).

Comment: Don't add "Solved" at your title. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out. This link was very helpful: https://butterflyofdream.wordpress.com/2012/09/10/how-to-assign-capslock-on-backspace-key-in-colemak/

Changing the backspace key to a caps lock key is as simple as typing this on the console:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 22 = Caps_Lock"
```

Comment: This seems to work, but I think the most important command now would be how to reset this back to Backspace: `xmodmap -e "keycode 22 = BackSpace"`

Answer (score 2):

The answer should be

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = BackSpace"
```

And to revert the action

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = Caps_Lock"
```

Answer (score 1):

In Gnome, KDE, Mate etc keyboard advanced settings there should be an option for that. For example, in Plasma:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Edit `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/de` (where `/de` is your language) and add this section in the first block, that you use in your language:

```
        # replace Caps with Backspace
        key <CAPS> { [ BackSpace            ] };
```

But I would recommend better to replace it with AltGr and them map AltGr+f to backspace:

```
        # replace Caps with AltGr
        key <CAPS> { [ ISO_Level3_Shift            ] };
        # Add Backspace to AltGr+f
        key <AC04> { [ f, F, BackSpace, BackSpace  ] };
```

So you can add more useful shortcuts like here: [Configure Caps Lock as AltGr and Arrows like in vim](https://askubuntu.com/a/898462/34298)